# Simple, Admin-Friendly LDAP daemon for Linux?

Tags: ldap

I tried to setup OpenLDAP in a small enterprise and realized that its configs are too far away from being geniously-short and intuitive.

Is there any Linux (preferably, Ubuntu) LDAP daemon that follows the [KISS-principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and integrate well with Linux & Windows? What are the drawbacks?

Comment: Maybe you can get further by asking for help on your OpenLDAP problems? I have set up several Debian LDAP servers and can now do it without much problems (after the third attempt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Zentyal](http://www.zentyal.org/) can be the solution: it offers a nice WEB-GUI for multiple services, including OpenLDAP.

Answer (score 2):

Though I have not used it much myself, if you are using Fedora, 389 directory server is pretty simple to setup by doing:

1. `sudo yum install 389-ds`
2. `sudo setup-ds-admin.pl`
3. Answer some questions and **poof** LDAP server.

They do also have windows password synchronization via an [AD Plugin](http://directory.fedoraproject.org/wiki/Download).

Answer (score 1):

ldap Kerberos dns and ntp

http://freeipa.org/